# How to add thumbnail to facebook scheduled LIVE VIDEO using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, facebook-live-api

I want to add thumbnail to facebook LIVE VIDEO using graph api. I saw some websites able to do that , they can add thumbnail to live video. there is no docs available to do that.

[image]

I tried to upload thumbnail to the live video attachment but not worked.

some website are able to add the thumbnail to the scheduled live video , see the above screenshot with thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no standard way of doing that. However, if you tried getting the data of the live video after the live stream has started, it will include an iframe that has the video ID in its source. So the process would be something like this:

1. Create the live video
2. Start the live stream
3. Get the live video data
4. Parse the iframe content and extract the value from the src attribute
5. Get the href query param from the extracted value
6. The last part of the href is the actual video ID that will show in feeds
7. Use that video ID to add the thumbnail
8. I would advise adding some latency before step #3 so that you can be sure that the video has been created in feeds.

Comment: I need this for scheduled live video. there is some platform they are able to add the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

**USE THIS**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/#Creating

- Include `event_params: {"cover" : "<thumbnail url>"}` in the request parameters
- Cover photo won't show up in timeline. (You need to click on more and then click on events)

Comment: thanks its working with test user , when try with other user i am getting error  {"error":{"message":"Unsupported request - method type: post","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AFdB8v6SeBeiVQsZt7wiIn8"}}